# How to import an array into a function and export resulted array

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have numpy arrays (x, y and z coordinates) and want to do some calculation using a function and finally export result of calculation as a numpy arrays (for simplicity I just copied a simple case):

```
point_1 = np.array ([[1., 2., 1.],
                   [0., 1., 1.]])
point_2 = np.array ([[0., 0., 1.],
                   [1., 0., 2.]])
a = 1.
b = 2.
c = 3.
d = 4.
```

In my function I want to use the second (`y`) and third (`z`) columns of each row of `point_1` and `point_2` arrays to calculate a new value for the first column (`x`) of the same row. In fact each row is a coordinate and I want to calculate a new `x` for each row. Then, I want to them a new array. This is also my function:

```
def fun_1(x, y, z):
    points_new = np.array([])
    new_x = -(d + b * y + c * z) / a
    points_new = np.append(points_new, new_x)
    return points_new
```

For the input, it is much more efficient for me to for example import the result of `np.vstack((point_1,point_2))` into my function (I mean `fun_1(np.vstack((point_1,point_2)`).
But, this function is not giving me my desired output. I want to have:

```
points_new=np.array ([[-11., 2., 1.],
                       [-9., 1., 1.],
                       [-7., 0., 1.],
                       [-10., 0., 2.]])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `map` function and modified version of `fun_1`

```
def fun_1(row):
    a, b, c, d = 1., 2., 3., 4.
    row[0] = -(d + b * row[1] + c * row[2]) / a
    return row

point_1 = np.array([[1., 2., 1.],[0., 1., 1.]])
point_2 = np.array([[0., 0., 1.],[1., 0., 2.]])

points_list = [point_1, point_2]
new_points = np.asarray(list(map(fun_1, [x for point in points_list for x in point])))
```

It works for all points that you append to the `points_list`.

Comment: Dear @Esi, Thanks for the efficient method you proposed. I do appreciate it. That's exactly what I wanted.